# Oracle 12c to 19c Internal Schema Export & Import

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, import, export, datapump

I want to exp & imp operations for APEX users from Oracle Database 12cR1 to 19c.

Data Pump Utility can't do that. When I try to export by using following parfile and command:

```
DUMPFILE=APEX.dmp
LOGFILE=APEXEXPLOG.log
SCHEMAS=APEX_PUBLIC_USER,APEX_040200,FLOWS_FILES
DIRECTORY=APEXEXP
CLUSTER=N
EXCLUDE=STATISTICS


expdp "'/ as sysdba'" PARFILE=/apexexp/apex_06012022.par
```

And when I try to traditional export, it also couldn't this operation:

```
exp \'/ as sysdba\' FILE=APEX_2.dmp LOG=APEXEXP_2log.log OWNER=APEX_PUBLIC_USER,APEX_040200,FLOWS_FILES STATISTICS=NONE
```

> About to export specified users ... EXP-00010: APEX_040200 is not a
> valid username EXP-00010: FLOWS_FILES is not a valid username

How can I provide it?

Comment: I don't think APEX v4.2 can run on Oracle 19c.

Comment: @MichaelKutz Hello Michael, so I have 2 more questions. If I want to provide just same data, how can I provide this? I need to transport same data. Other question, with same data and higher APEX version will it be compatible?

Comment: I've always kept APEX and Data schemas separate. I just need to move the Data Scema. APEX 4.2 to 5.x had enough differences that it was easier for me to te-write the application  than to fix everything that broke. At that point, I'd migrate to the latest.

Comment: In addition, you should _NOT_ be running any of the export/import utilities as sysdba. This is very plainly stated in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-D5455260-C28C-475F-9E0E-2BE227E7F0E3)  - "_Do not start Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users._"

Answer (score 1):

Oracle APEX 4.2 is not supported beyond Oracle 12cR1. To get to database version 19c, you will first have to

1. Upgrade your existing APEX in the 12cR1 database to a minimum of version 18.2
2. Update anything in your application broken by the upgrade
3. Install that APEX target version separately in your 19c database
4. Export/import your applications using the APEX export and import utilities, not datapump.

Never try to migrate Oracle internal schemas between systems using datapump; they generally contain instance-specific metadata that will break upon import to the target - it will *not* be a clean migration.

As Michael suggested:

- You should also keep your application/data schema separate from the internal APEX schemas; this will make future migrations of your data simpler. As it is, you would probably need to do a table-level export/import rather than schema-level to get just your application data and avoid any of Oracle's internal APEX tables.
- Given the wide jump in version numbers, you may indeed be better off rebuilding your application from scratch rather than trying to upgrade. You will have to determine that for yourself, though.

Comment: Hello Pete, I solved this problem about 1 week ago. I just forgot to answer my own question. Thank you.